# List view with different images

Tags: android, listview

Code for the listview which contains different images in each row.This needs to be pulled from xml but not from hard coded strings in .class file. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link

Link : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html